# C++ program does not work on some inputs

Tags: c++, string

Hallo

I have this assignment to print only alphabets in a C++ string. It works for most input but when `[` and `]` are present in the input they are printed as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        string input = "THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG]";

        for(int i=0;i<input.size();i++) 
        {
                if(input[i] >='A' && input[i] <= 'z')
                //if(isalpha(input[i]))
                        cout<<input[i];
        }
        cout<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I compiled your program and it works as expected. What compiler did you use, what options?

Comment: Does it print ] even if the isalpha check is present?

Comment: It works fine with isalpha but not with one before that. Why ?

Comment: Because characters '[' and ']' are after 'A' and before 'z', as a few people already posted.

Comment: `'A`' and `'z`' are just standins for numbers.  `'A'` and `'z'` are 65 and 122 respectively.  As you notice, 122-65 is not 51 (51 = 26 * 2 - 1.  x >= 1 && x <= 4 would be ok if x is 1, 2, 3, or 4, so 4 different numbers, even though 4-1 = 3).  So there are six extra things in there that cannot possibly be letters.  Try this loop: `for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'z'; c++) { cout << c; }` and you can see what they are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if(input[i] >='A' && input[i] <= 'z')
              ^^^                ^^^
```

You are using uppercase `'A'` and lowercase `'z'`.

The range `A-z` is not same as `A-Z` + `a-z`.
The ASCII value of `Z` is `90` and that of `a` is `97`.
 *Between them there are 6 other characters which you are considering as alphabets.*

```
ASCII value   Character
------------------------
90            Z 
91            [ \ 
92            \  \
93            ]   \  your range A-z includes these.
94            ^   /
95            _  /
96            ` /
97            a
```

To allow only uppercase and lowercase alphabets you should use:

```
if( (input[i] >='A' && input[i] <= 'Z') || (input[i] >='a' && input[i] <= 'z') )
```

or even better just use `isalpa`:

```
if(isalpha(input[i]))
```

Comment: @Cgnaik - 'A' being 65 and 'Z' being 90 is just an arbitrary convention (one such convention is called ASCII) that most computers happen to follow.  There are computers out there that do not follow it, and have a mapping in which the letters do not even map to a continuous range of numbers (EBCDIC being the name of a convention with this property).  `isalpha` works properly on those computers as well, but the code `letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z'` would not.  It is better to use `isalpha`. See http://www.diycalculator.com/sp-ascii.shtml for an interesting example.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because there are some special characters in the A-z range.
You need to use the A-Z range, and then the a-z range individually, if you want to filter out those special characters like [ and ]

Comment: Won't isalpha take care of those characters ?

Comment: It should, and it does for me at least;)

Comment: To be pedantic, contiguity of A-Z and a-z ranges isn't guaranteed by the standard. Of course that happens to be the case in most of the implementations out there today, but in any case, why not let `isalpha` to take care of that?

Comment: Yes. I just mentioned why some special characters were appearing. Indeed isalpha is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this line:

```
if(input[i] >='A' && input[i] <= 'z')
```

And your program is working fine..

Answer (score 1):

`isalpha` should return 0 on square brackets, since it is defined by the standard (C++03 §7.4.1.2.2) to

> tests for any character for which `isupper` or `islower` is true, or any character that is one of a locale-specific set of alphabetic characters for which none of `iscntrl`, `isdigit`, `ispunct`, or `isspace` is true. In the "C" locale, `isalpha` returns true only for the characters for which `isupper` or `islower` is true.

and they shouldn't be considered uppercase or lowercase characters.

On the other hand, your

```
if(input[i] >='A' && input[i] <= 'z')
```

is wrong, since the ['A','z'] range usually includes also nonalphabetic characters, in particular, in standard ASCII, the characters `` [ \ ] ^ _ ` ``.

So, you should either split your check in two parts (to check if the character is in range [`'A'`,`'Z'`] or [`'a'`,`'z'`]) or simply use `isalpha` and forget about this stuff.

By the way, the standard doesn't even mandate that the [`'A'`,`'Z'`] and [`'a'`,`'z'`] ranges must be contiguous (it only has a guarantee of contiguity for [`'0'`,`'9'`], and in facts the original EBCDIC codepage was a real mess to deal with, since to check if a character was alphabetical you couldn't check for the character to be in those ranges. Thus, to be strictly standard you can't even expect that

```
if((input[i] >='A' && input[i] <= 'Z') || (input[i] >='a' && input[i] <= 'z'))
```

will work as you expect.

Long story short: if it's not just for homework, use `isalpha`, which is guaranteed to work whichever strange codepage your platform uses.

Answer (score 0):

or, `#include<cctype>`  and use `std::isalpha(input[i])`